# Using jquery to find elements with data-attribute that has a specific value?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a basic way via jquery to find all elements that have a data-attribute with a specific value and return those elements as an array?

i.e. `<span data-productID="7">My product</span>`

Comment: note, data attributes are normalized to be all lowercase. If you want it to be represented by `productId` in jQuery's `.data` method, use `data-product-id="7"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for selecting elements with a specific attribute value is:

```
[attr_name = attr_value]
```

In your specific case, this would be:

```
$('span[data-product="7"]');
```

This returns a jQuery collection (not an Array), but it can be accessed much like an array using numerical indices. If you really need an array (perhaps in order to use Array prototype methods), you can use:

```
$('span[data-product="7"]').makeArray();
```

Comment: What is the collection returned a collection of? i.e. elements? I am trying to figure out how to manipulate the classes of each element in the collection.

Comment: @JohnS The collection wraps elements that match the expression in the selector string. To apply a class to the elements in a collection, use `$(selector).addClass('myclass')`. To remove a class, use `removeClass`, in much the same way.